# twitter-bootstrap: make a row (div) background image auto scale and center to fill 100%?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, scale, centering

I've got a Bootstrap page where some rows have background images. Is there a way (preferably css) to scale such a background image, so that it's always centered and fills the div 100%?

So I don't mean a fullscreen background image for the entire page (like [this](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)), it just needs to fill the div (typically a row in my bootstrap container).

I mean like so:

[image: different formats]

So no matter the display resolution and the actual screen size of the div, its background image should scale accordingly so it **entirely fills the div**. The image should *not* be stretched out of proportions, which means that part of the image will typically fall outside the div, either up/down or left/right (unless the div just so happens to have the exact same aspect ratio as the image).

Also the image should be **centered**, i.e. the middle of the background image should be in the middle of the div.

I've tried all sorts of things with `background-size:100% auto` or `auto 100%` which seems to work OK in one direction, but I can't seem to find a generic solution that works in all cases.

Comment: what are you current results?

Comment: @knitevision: closest I could get was [this](http://jsfiddle.net/15me8nkc/) which does not work correctly if the display becomes very narrow (like on a vertical-oriented phone screen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure, you could apply the same idea to any element:

```
yourdiv  {
     background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
     /* and one of these: */
     background-size:contain;
     background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: more examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images

Comment: Thanks, that worked pretty well! I only removed the `fixed` (in this case the background was supposed to scroll along and stay centered in the div). Using `background-size:cover;` is seems to work on Firefox, Chrome, and Safari (not sure about IE but I'll take my chances).

Comment: would you recommend adding the browser-specific properties as well, i.e. `-webkit-background-size: cover;` and `-moz-background-size: cover;` and `-o-background-size: cover;` for compatibility reasons? Or is it also possible they do more harm than good?